# insert optional input form to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

In html forms we have input elements that users can fill it optionally, such as address2,
What is the best solution while users fill some of this fields and insert just them into database?
Should we check one by one if its empty insert null into database or you have better solution?

```
$userdata = empty($_POST['userdata']) ? "null" : $_POST['userdata'];
```

Comment: You could also use a foreach loop to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

modify your database for allow null values and in your sql only put the value:

```
$addres2 = $_POST["addres2"]; // if is null $addres = null and in sql was null
$sql = "insert into users values ('$id','$name','$addres1','$addres2')";
```

if allow null values don't need check the value, only need check the value of others normally

Answer (score 0):

When you start getting into detecting if data has been tainted for security such as in [Essential PHP Security - 1.2.3. Simple Is Beautiful](http://sharepoint.serviceatschool.nl/Applicatieontwikkelaars%20s1a/SECU%20(Security)/Essential-PHP-Security.pdf) you will learn that it is better to set the variable 1st then check to see if has been altered such as

```
$userdata = "";

if (isset($_POST['userdata']))
{
    $userdata = $_POST['userdata'];
}
```